# How can you tell who are related when trying to make babies?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I noticed that a lot of times I have pairings that will start talking and say something like "Nothing like hanging out with families."

How can I tell who are related other than dropping them into the room and wait for them to start talking?

Comment: You could always have only one universal father :D

Comment: @Ealhad [related](http://haremking.tv/)

Comment: @ardaozkal I'm not sure wether I should thank you or not.

Comment: Another classic Arqade question title.

Answer (score 7):

There's the obvious of them having the same last name, but besides that if they're both in the bedroom and they're related they say something like"there's nothing like hanging out with family", instead of the usual pick up lines.

These are the only ways of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You could devise a naming scheme that would allow you to track genealogy (you can rename when a baby is born). A simple scheme might have woman A and man B, whos kids are AB1, AB2, etc. This type of scheme might only work for a few generations though. This is just an example; I realize there are some flaws with it that might prevent it from working.

It might be helpful to know if members of the same tree can ever start mating again.

Comment: It tracks at least to great-grandchild, although I wonder if it still tracks if you kill a link-dweller between two people in the family chain.

Answer (score 0):

Check the dwellers' conversation when you assign them to the living quarters. If they say, "There's nothing like hanging out with family," they're either parent/child or siblings.

To avoid this, I name my dwellers with the last name of the opposite gender parent, with a numeric generational tag. So if Jane Doe and John Smith have a girl, I assign the last name as Smith-2. If it's a boy, the last name would be Doe-2.

The only flaw in this system is if the same set of parents have two opposite gender siblings.